# Extract numbers in SQL teratata

Tags: sql, substring, extract, teradata

any other more elegant way to extract from the third character to the anteultimate one?

```
select SUBSTR(TRIM(23441255739), 3, LENGTH(TRIM(23441255739))-4);
44125573
```

Comment: What are you calling `trim()` on what looks like a numeric constant?

Comment: You could use `REGEXP_REPLACE(TRIM(23441255739),'^(..)(.*)(.)$','\2')` though I'm not sure that's more "elegant".

Comment: Note that the last record should not be shown either. The final 9 does not go.

Comment: The constant is assumed to be of type DECIMAL so the TRIM (which is actually being used to implicitly CAST to VARCHAR using the default format) appends a decimal point. In that case you could just add another `.` to the third group: `'^(..)(.*)(..)$'` or you could use explicit CAST with FORMAT to avoid generating the decimal point.

Comment: You can even allow for the trailing decimal to be optional: